# Code compare tool for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, beyondcompare

What is the best code compare tool available for Linux? I have been using Beyond Compare in Windows and am looking for something similar for Ubuntu with nautilus integration.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) , there is a [nautilus extension](https://github.com/mablo/nautilus-meld-compare) for it too.

Comment: apt-get install meld nautilus-compare

Comment: What a fantastically useful program. I love free software.

Answer (score 13):

Beyond compare works on Linux, too, there's even a `.deb`.

Comment: It also adds commands to the "Scripts" submenu in Nautilus's context menu.

Comment: BC has folder compare, so you can see instantly which files have differences. If you have hundreds of files in many folders and subfolders, that's a big plus.

Answer (score 8):

I liked meld when I tried it on ubuntu, but I was using it with rapidsvn

**One Line Installation Command:**

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

**Website:** http://meld.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7):

I use Meld - http://meld.sourceforge.net/
You can install it from the Ubuntu repository

Answer (score 5):

I think [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) would be it [i.e., the best]

Answer (score 4):

meld does not have ftp/sftp comparison. 
go for BC3 for Ubuntu, still the best one around

Answer (score 3):

or since no one else mentioned it in the first minute....

why not meld?

Comment: 6 ppl mentioned it after 10min at about the same time :)

Answer (score 3):

I use diff and patch on the command line.

Comment: @Chris Harrison: Hehe, since you make a cynical remark - use http://www.diffchecker.com/ , works on any OS - without installation.

Answer (score 2):

In short:
http://meld.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I find [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) very hard to beat. You may go so far as to say it's beyond compare!

Comment: It also works on more operating systems than I use on a daily basis!